# How can I use Moq to test that two methods inside a C# finalizer have been called on GC?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, garbage-collection, moq, finalizer

I'm trying to write a unit test that makes sure two methods in a finalizer have been called. My problem is that I can't assert on a mock that has gone out of scope. Let me show my problem with code:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    MyClass() { }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        this.MethodA()
        this.MethodB()
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Finalize_NormalDestruction_MethodAandMethodBCalled()
{
    var myMock = new myMock();

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Assert.IsTrue(myMock.IsMethodACalled);  // Fails, myMock never went OOS
    Assert.IsTrue(myMock.IsMethodBCalled);  // Fails, myMock never went OOS
}

[TestMethod]
public void Finalize_NormalDestruction_MethodAandMethodBCalled()
{
    {
        var myMock = new myMock();
    }

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Assert.IsTrue(myMock.IsMethodACalled);  // Doesn't compile, myMock is OOS
    Assert.IsTrue(myMock.IsMethodBCalled);  // Doesn't compile, myMock is OOS
}
```

Is there a way to use Moq to test that a finalizer has run? I've been able to manually test it with break points, but I would like an automated test.

Comment: This type should be implementing `IDisposable` to allow for explicit disposal, even if it also disposes of those objects in a finalizer.  Your automated tests can then use explicit disposal to make sure that all of the required resources are cleaned up.  As is you're essentially trying to write an automated test to say that the GC calls the finalizer on objects before cleaning them up.  First off, *that isn't actually a guarantee*; it's entirely valid for the object to *never be finalized*.  Second, your unit tests should be testing *this class*, not the GC.

Comment: I completely agree that I don't want to test the GC. Implementing IDisposable and wrapping some production code in using blocks/using .Dispose() in tests should work well -- I was unsure if there was another way to use Moq to test this.

Comment: I don't have the time to write up a full length example and test it, but I think the way to do this test would be with a [weak reference that tracks resurrection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13915673/517852) so you don't have to store a strong reference and can get the object back after the finalizer has been run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the finalizer to run your code cannot have any live references to the instance. You have two options if you really want to verify this in your test.

You could store the fact that the methods have run as static members of the type. However, you'll have to do any necessary book keeping yourself such that you can make sure that it ran for the instance you're interested in.

Alternatively, you can let the finalizer resurrect the instance. I wouldn't recommend to do that just for the sake of testing though.

Comment: I agree that letting the finalizer resurrect the instance or storing methods that have run in static functions just doesn't feel right. For now, the fix I put in was to have the finalizer call another method in the class. Then for testing purposes I used Moq's Verify call to check that the methods had been called.