# What is the use of RemoveHandler in Weak Event Pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, weak-references

As per [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns):

> The weak event pattern can be used whenever a listener needs to
>   register for an event, but **the listener does not explicitly know when
>   to unregister**.

[A sample code here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43201093/3834) illustrates that when using `WeakEventManager`, not explicitly calling [`RemoveHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh161304(v=vs.110).aspx) will *not* cause memory leak.

So my question is, why is the method `RemoveHandler` even there in `WeakEventManager` class? Isn't it completely unnecessary? When it becomes necessary?

Comment: There are cases when you don't want to receive events from a source any more.

Comment: @SimonMourier, maybe you can expand that into a proper answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't it completely unnecessary?

No. How are you supposed to unsubsribe (explicitly) if there isn't a `RemoveHandler` method?

> When it becomes necessary?

Whenever you want to unsubsribe from the event subscription explicitly.

If you don't call `RemoveHandler`, the event handling continues until the garbage collecor collects the listener.