# How to subscribe to an event without preventing garbage collection?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, garbage-collection

Let's say `AppConfiguration.Instance` is a singleton.

Now let's say my UI dynamically adds a button that should change it's text if the configuration is changed, so my app could do:

```
AppConfiguration.Instance.Changed += Changed_Handler;
```

On the button's code, but I don't wanna do that because that will prevent garbage collecion of the button after the user navigates to another screen and the button gets removed from the form

My question is: Is there a design pattern for listening to an event without preventing garbage collection asides from manually unsubscribing to the event with `AppConfiguration.Instance.Changed -= Changed_Handler;`?

Comment: To the downvoter: why is this a bad question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing the and question and doing my last search-before-posting on weak bindings I came across the [weak event pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that does exactly what I want